# No LAN-connection - how to diagnose possible hardware problem

Tags: debian, ethernet

My oldish desktop PC, running stable Debian, won't connect to LAN anymore. Since other computers in the same network don't have this problem (even using the same cable) I strongly suspect a hardware problem with the onboard ethernet port (I recently plugged in another computer using the same cable, maybe i simply broke a pin when plugging the cable back in). Before I rush out and buy an ethernet card, what can I do to diagnose the problem with the software tools my operating system offers

Comment: Never known an ethernet connector breaking a pin, if it wasn't for the plastic safety that keeps them in place.   Does dmesg show any movement when you remove and put back the connector?

Comment: If you have it installed `ethtool` is probably the best low level diagnostic  program. Otherwise `ifconfig` and look for Rx packets being non-zero and flags including UP.

Comment: First step is `ifconfig` or `ip -s link`, look at the stats and counters. Second steps are `ethtool`, looking at `dmesg` for errors, manually doing a `dhclient` together with a `tcpdump` to see if DHCP is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desktop network cards almost always have a LED to indicate connection (and often a second one tracking data I/O).

If there is no LED, then try plugging the cable out and in again, and run `dmesg` to see whether anything happens, for example:

```
[248510.165619] e1000: eth0 NIC Link is Down
[248510.168904] e1000 0000:00:03.0 eth0: Reset adapter
[248512.277754] e1000: eth0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX
```

If there is a LED and it stays off, and/or no activity is detected by the kernel, then the network card is either broken or seriously borked. I had this happen once, but long ago, because I had installed the wrong driver - I think a 8139A instead of something else or vice versa. But even then, it was apparent in the syslog (it said something like, "eth0: 8139too blah blah: No so-and-so chip was found")

Also check the output of `lspci`. It should say something apropos an Ethernet controller:

```
00:03.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 02)
00:08.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 02)
```

This is a newer (still a bit long in the tooth) Dell machine:

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme BCM5722 Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme BCM5751 Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express (rev 21)
```

If you don't see any Ethernet controllers, then the card has been unseated, or is seriously broken. A bent or oxidised pin would result in `lspci` seeing a card, a lot of complaints in /var/log/syslog and dmesg, and no connection.